# How to inject a mock Pinia store to a Vue component based on routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, pinia

I am using Vue together with Pinia stores and Vue-router.
I have a component `Projects.vue` that uses a `project.store.ts` to display some data on the screen when a user goes to someSite.com/projects:

```
<!-- Projects.vue -->
<template>
 <div v-each="project in projects">
  {{project.name}}
 </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
 import { useProjectStore } from "../stores/project.store";

 const projectStore = useProjectStore();
 const { projects } = storeToRefs(projectStore);

 projectStore.getAll();
</script> 

<!-- project.store.ts -->
export const useProjectStore = defineStore({
  id: "project",
  state: () =>
    ({
      projects: [],
    } as ProjectStoreState),

  actions: {
    async getAll() {
      this.projects = await fetch.get(`${baseUrl}`);
    }
  },
});
```

What I want to do is to introduce Demo functionality, where if a user goes to someSite.com/demo/projects, it's served the same Projects.vue component, however with static data that I've defined in the code.

I was thinking to create a `project.store.mock.ts`, which follows the same interface just does

```
actions: {
    async getAll() {
      this.projects = [{name: "project1"}]
    }
  },
```

However, I am struggling to find a way to *inject* a different store based on the route. This might of course be a completely wrong way to approach it, but I would like to keep the same component, just present different data (data from different sources) based on routing

Comment: It's unnecessary to mock the whole store. getAll could be mocked instead, or fetch result. It's unclear what "inject a different store based on the route" actually means.

Comment: I need to mock all the functions in each store. So figured that maybe I could pass a store to a component instead of importing inside of the component. And them pass a different store depending on the route. And was hoping that the ‘depending on the route’ part could be done in the router config. So that components/stores would not need to be route-aware

Comment: This could be done in many ways and this really depends on your case. You could make use of DI and use `provide(useProjectStore())` and `inject('projectStore')` instead of using useProjectStore directly. Or fetch.get could be extracted to services and swapped, because a store is more than a bunch of requests and multiple copies would result in duplicate code